# Вывести содержимое главной страницы введенной ссылки

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Есть задание определить, существует ли сайт по заданному адресу, если есть - вывести содержание главной страницы. Использовать явно метод GET. Вот как я выводил размер, как сделать так же только получив содержание страницы?

```
val url = URL(urlString)
                try {
                    val httpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                    httpURLConnection.requestMethod = "GET"
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0")
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US")
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json")
                    if (httpURLConnection.responseCode == 200) {
                        it.onSuccess("Size is ${httpURLConnection.contentLenght}")
                    } else {
                        it.onError(Throwable("Website is not available"))
                    }
```

Comment: является ли сайт с заданной адресу - это предложение я бы перефразировал немного, а то мне лично не очень понятно))

Comment: Не заметил, задание на украинском просто, переводчиком переводил))

Comment: вам нужно проверить просто наличие сайта, или какого-то определенного ресурса?

Comment: ну там просто нужно проверить существует ли заданный сайт, это я знаю как делать через responseCode. Я не понимаю как сделать "вывести содержание главной страницы". Может какой то метод существует, или ещё что то

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 1):

Получить сайт можно при помощи такого способа:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String ... urls) 
        {
            try
            {
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
                //String j = (String) uc.getContent();
                uc.setDoInput(true);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                    a.append(inputLine);
                in.close();

                return a.toString();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.getMessage();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

и получение при помощи класса:

```
MyTask taskLoad = new MyTask();
taskLoad.execute("http://10.0.0.8/mybiren/JSON.php?day=Monday");
```

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723714/how-to-read-and-use-the-content-of-a-website-in-android-app) так же есть подобный вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо но немного не то, это я нашел как делать, вопрос состоит в том, как теперь получить содержимое страницы

Comment: то есть вы не знаете как вывести содержимое вебстраницы? или получить что-то с нее?

Comment: Да. Как вообще её получить. Вывести не проблема, а как получить я понятия не имею

Comment: @dgg4re, обновил ответ посмотрите пожалуйста :)